# Acessar propriedades de vídeos em "Video content sites"

Tags: php

Como faço para obter as propriedades (duração, resolução, titulo, hash) dos videos hospedados em sites como [liveleak](http://www.liveleak.com/view?i=4e8_1423673430), [hulu](http://www.hulu.com/watch/750475), [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OEQ_4vLFXlc), é possível baixar o *header* destes videos?

Tenho uma aplicação em PHP que irá consumir estes dados, que também é em PHP que estou tentando fazer isto, tenho conhecimento que alguns dos sites possuem uma API própria que facilitaria bastante o trabalho porem planejo algo mais genérico pois a maioria não possui API.